# Saving file on documents library Windows 8 C#

Tags: c#, onedrive, windows-8.1

I'm creating a simple app for windows 8 that writes me a xml file to documents library.

The problem is when i'm save the file, it saves it on skydrive and i want to save it on c:\Users\pc-name\Documents. I'm using KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary and updated the manifest to save xml files too, otherwise i couldn't save any file in it.

```
public static async void XmlSaveFreeChallenge(Challenge currentChallenge)
{
    var challenge = new XElement("Challenge");
    var docSave = new XDocument(challenge);
    challenge.Add(new XAttribute("Name", currentChallenge.Template));

    var pontos = new XElement("Type", currentChallenge.Type);
    docSave.Descendants("Challenge").FirstOrDefault().Add(pontos);

    var folder = KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary;
    var outputStream = await folder.OpenStreamForWriteAsync("CaiMUfiles\\output\\Desafios\\" + currentChallenge.Template + ".xml", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
    var ms = new MemoryStream();
    docSave.Save(outputStream, SaveOptions.None);
    await ms.CopyToAsync(outputStream);
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

The user gets to choose where the Documents library points. See the following option: settings charm -> Change PC Settings -> SkyDrive -> Save documents to SkyDrive by default

I'm not sure if it's possible for your app to override the user's choice there. Even if it is possible, it's probably better to respect the user's choice.

Answer (score 0):

What Isaac McGarvey said is correct nevertheless there might by something that you can do. i did not found a way how to programmatically switch default saving folder for libraries but you still have access to all folders that is included in libraries. The only think is that you need to know absolute path so if you can save the path before then you can use this to get desired folder :

```
StorageFolder folder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync("AbsolutePath");
```

and then you can start enumerating creating or whatever you need. The problem is that if you use for example

```
List<StorageFolder> folder = await KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary.GetFoldersAsync();
```

you wont get folder for Documents and folder for SkyDrive and folder for other linked folders to libraries you will just get all folders that is inside all of these folders in one list which mean you cannot choose where to save file.

I hope this helps a bit.

Comment: Just For the record KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary is NOT Implemented in WindowsPhone 8

Comment: well that is truth but irrelevant to this question/answer/discussion

Comment: well under the question there is tag windows-8.1. i think that it says all. Although i get your point that for someone the question might not be that clear and it can be said better.